# Cant Find Win10 Startup Folder Programmatically C#

Tags: c#

In Windows 10 running this simple code throws a directory not found exception. I can navigate to the directory manually fine. What gives?

```
shortcut_location_root = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);

if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(shortcut_location_root))
{   
  //FALLS IN HERE
    shortcut_location_root =
      Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup";

//BLOWS UP HERE DIRECTORY NOT FOUND
 if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(shortcut_location_root, "someFile" + ".url")))
 {
     //do stuff
 }
```

Comment: have you tried debugging, taking the path and seeing if you can manually go to the path that you generate ?

Comment: Yes I can manually goto the path (its hidden but I can manually navigate there)

Comment: Try to use Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonStartup instead of Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup

Comment: @RandRandom I am using .net 3.5 it doesnt look like  CommonStartup is available option

Comment: works for me. also, the first call (the one with SpecialFolder.Startup) does return a path, namely "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup". which user is running this code? is it an asp.net application pool identity or something like that?

Comment: I am logging in as a non admin user. On a desktop machine. Could this be a permissions issue? I could say this, but then why can I manually navigate to the directory?

Comment: me too. just switched to 3.5 and retried, no difference, works. strange. what is your observed runtime value for the second call to `GetFolderPath`? does that user have a roaming domain profile?

Comment: The code works for me on a win10 home edition. On win10 enterprise doesnt. Now im not sure anyone is gonna be able to reproduce

Comment: @nlstack01 the path looks fine when i generated it, have you tried running as Administrator ?

Comment: try `Directory.Exists` instead or before `File.Exists` to prove that it is caused by the path and not the file.

Comment: Try running as administrator and see if the same happens.

Comment: @dlatikay when I login into a fresh machine. The code breaks. If I restart the machine then try the code works

Answer (score 0):

If the error says "directory not found" then the directory does not exist. The location of known folders is stored by the system in the registry, so it doesn't necessarily exist just because a registry entry exists. Rather the registry entry specifies where the folder should be placed if needed.

Probably what is happening is the folder is being created by the shell (Explorer.exe) "on demand" and that's why you can browse to it.

Just call `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory` first. This will create the directory if it does not exist, or open it if it does.